# White band to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

[image]

Why is there an annoying white band to the right of my website? I tried `min-width:100vw;`,`width:100%;`, but to no avail. If anyone could help, that would be great.

MWE [Here](https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/bGBPMmm?editors=1000).

Comment: Try removing `margin: -3%` from this block (MVE does not have this white band)

Comment: @AndrewEvt Yup, tried that already. Makes no visible change on my iPad. MWE doesn't have this on laptop for me, but it has it on my iPad. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah ... no; `.riddle` is part of my interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. All I had to do is remove `margin: -3%` from all the section blocks, as advised by @Andrew Evt. Don't know why I put that there in the first place. This must be a record -- **-2 votes in 2 minutes**. So much for "We <3 Developers"

Comment: It's because you did not provide a minimal reproduceable example and you posted a picture of your code.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze It says (1) "MWE here" and (2) That's not a picture of my *code*, it's meant to show the white band. But thanks for the clarification. Much better than beating down my question as if I committed some crime.

Comment: There's something wrong with SO. I'm now banned from asking questions, just because I asked three "bad" questions. This is a very repressive community, and "We <3 Developers" couldn't be farther from the truth.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `style= 'margin: -3%;'`
if this (`margin: -3%`) was from Bulma go to your style file and add `!important` like this:

```
.hero-body{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```